# In an infinite universe, would there be an infinite amount of matter as well?

Tags: cosmology, universe, atoms

Or would you eventually reach a point past which there is no matter? How would an infinite amount of matter work? Would it sort of "loop back" to the beginning, or would it be entirely unique the whole way through?

Comment: Yes, in an accelerating expanding universe one will, eventually, reach a point where there is practically no matter: it's everywhere because the average matter density goes to zero everywhere. What happens "after that" is unknown. You have to start thinking about homogeneity of the universe seriously: if something is true in one place, it's true everywhere else.

Comment: In an infinite universe, there could be an infinite amount of matter, and it could still seem nearly empty: compare the infinite number of integers with the real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not easy questions and there is no definite answer for them. There are plenty of cosmological models which we believe to be at least partialy true, and they do adress some of these questions. However, it is difficult to be entirely confident in their validity. I think most of cosmologists believe that there is infinite amount of matter in the world, and the world itself is infinite. It is "unique the whole way through". However, there are also cosmological models in which universe is finite and therefore only finite amount of matter exists.